# C# For Loop Retains Value In Uninstantiated Variable

Tags: c#

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int taco;
    var randy = new Random();
    taco = randy.Next();
}
```

I'm confused to why taco retains a value. Basically, if I put a breakpoint at "int taco" on the first iteration I can look and see that taco is 0. On the second iteration taco has the value from the previous iteration when I check it and I can use it in the immediate window. Can somebody tell me why this is the case?

Comment: Because you didn't actually code `int taco = 0;`?

Comment: Instantiate "randy" outside of your loop.

Comment: On the second iteration, do you execute the int taco; line or just stay over it with your breakpoint? If you do not execute it, it will indeed stay at the same value in the debugger window.

Comment: I really like the variable called randy for some reason.  He'll be gutted when his pals bob and pete get taken by the garbage collector...

Comment: The API for Random() says that if no argument is supplied, a time-dependent seed is used, so randy.Next() should, in theory, produce a pseudorandom number.
Assuming `int taco;` actually reads `int taco = 0;`, what *might* be happening is that the value you see in the immediate window is simply the leftover value from before...because the reinitialization hasn't taken place yet. Put the breakpoint down a line and you should see the updated results. Better yet, put the breakpoint AFTER the `taco = randy.Next();` and you'll see the new value.

Comment: taco is not out of scope until you exit the loop.  'int taco;' reserves a stack entry for the duration of the loop.  If you had something like int taco = 0; you would reinitialize on each iteration, but that's not what you're telling it to do.  All you're saying is hold 4 bytes open as an int - I'll fill it with values whenever I want.

Comment: @BrandonMoretz The whole point of the question is that it's inside the loop, and as such the OP expects it to have no relation to the previous loop's variable, but through the debugger he sees that it has a value other than 0 when it's first declared.  Now it turns out this doesn't matter, because whatever value is there *must* be overridden before it could ever be read through managed C# code (the C# compiler ensures this) but the use of a debugger doesn't have that restriction.

Comment: @Servy This wasn't an answer to the question, hence why it was a comment and not an answer. It was just a general, you know, comment on things not to do.

Comment: @BrandonMoretz But it makes sense for the variable to be inside the loop, not outside the loop.  Why would he want to move it outside the loop?

Comment: Isn't the cause that `int taco;` is declared inside the loop. Because of this it is created and disposed each iteration again, and the debugger shows the value in the old memory location which at that time is not assigned to `taco` at all. If the declaration were outside the loop, `taco` would not be disposed and it would continue to reference the memory location holding the value, as it updates each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `int taco` doesn't actually create an int named 'taco'.

When the compiler has to compile your code, it will have to allocate all the memory it needs.

When you write code in C/C++ for instance, the moment you declare a variable, its value is not set to anything, so it's going to hold whatever value was stored previously (which can lead to nasty bugs).

In C#, the compiler won't let you access variables, unless they were defined beforehand.

Comment: `In C#, the compiler won't let you access variables, unless they were defined beforehand.` Except through the debugger, which lets you see things that you ordinarily couldn't, hence the cause of the confusion here.

Comment: @Servy The debugger is not the compiler. If in your code you try to access a variable before setting it (or if branches exist that may lead to accessing a variable that is not set), the compiler will refuse to compile your code. In the case of the debugger, the code is already compiled, and all it does is read and display the values stored in memory.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I wasn't sure. I originally noticed this in a loop that created handles to C++ code as out variables that were causing issues. I wasn't sure if the debugger was making a copy of taco or if it was just referencing the same spot in memory. It just seemed odd that the value was still present in the next iteration.

Answer (score 5):

Put the breakpoint on the *next* line after the declaration (and initialization) of `taco`.

> I'm confused to why `taco` retains a value.

It's not retaining the value, you're just seeing the mechanics of the debugger not having yet seen the declaration and initialization on the next iteration of the loop. It's still looking at the same *memory location* that `taco` occupies, but `taco` conceptually doesn't hold that value because you can't use it in code.

**Note that right now, in your code, you are actually missing the initialization that you state you have in your text**. If you continue as your code as written, the debugger exhibit the behavior of showing the value from the previous loop until you reach the assignment on the last line because, as an implementation detail, the storage for `taco` will be the same place on the stack every iteration through the loop. Again, `taco` is not actually retaining this value. If you try to write this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int taco;
    Console.WriteLine(taco);
    var randy = new Random();
    taco = randy.Next();
}
```

the compiler will yell at you that you're using an unassigned local. This basically demonstrates that you can't actually use that previous value; that is, you're merely seeing an artifact of how local variables are stored on the stack and how the debugger works; that memory location still holds that value, but you can't actually use it in code at all. So, the *memory location* retains the value, but *`taco`* does not because it's not valid to refer to the storage location used by `taco` until it's explicitly initialized.

Comment: taco won't be reset. `int taco;` will not necessarily change the value of taco. In particular, trying to use `taco` immediately after its declaration will result in a compile time error. Uninitialised variables cannot be used in C#.

Comment: If he puts in an initialization, it will. Read his text: "Basically, if I put a breakpoint at "`int taco = 0`"" His code doesn't match his text, and that's why I put initialization in a parenthetical. I'm stressing the importance of actually having the initialization for what I said to be true.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the code after I copy pasted. The "int taco = 0" was irrelevant. I was wondering why it still had the value related to taco before taco was set to anything else.

Comment: Implementation detail. Every iteration of the loop uses the same storage location on the stack for `taco`. Note that `taco` doesn't actually have that value, it's just the memory location that is used for `taco` still has that value. `taco` isn't valid until you initialize it. That is, there is no way for you to get that "previous value" out of `taco` in code. It's just an implementation detail.

Answer (score -1):

In the context of the next iteration, `taco` is uninitialized and can be anything.